# How to combine identical tables into one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 100s of millions of unique rows spread across 12 tables in the same database.  They all have the same schema/columns.  Is there a relatively easy way to combine all of the separate tables into 1 table?

I've tried importing the tables into a single table, but given this is a HUGE size of files/rows, SQL Server is making me wait a long time as if I was importing from a flat file.  There has to be an easier/faster way, no?

Comment: Why did you use 12 separate tables if the schema is the same?  Why do you need them all in one table?

Comment: Why bother? Why not just create a view that unions them, and reference the view from now on?

Comment: FYI: Importing from a flat file shouldn't be slow either.  I suspect that your configuration is a bit overloaded.

Comment: Using a UNION will not perform well, UNLESS the tables are structured along an axis like time (monthly, quarterly, etc) and you can leverage specialized index types of your server to help.

Comment: Why it was designed like that? Do tables are located on the same drive? What is the version of the server? Maybe there is some partitioning? Above all, if you decide to do it, do in portions not in a single `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Paul I assumed the underlying tables are indexed, and depending on the query patterns SQL Server should be able to eliminate them just as easily as it would do with a huge unpartitioned table that combines them all. Nothing is going to be ideal here I think.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if the OP ends up with a solution using UNION, if he or she isn't concerned with duplicates between the tables, UNION ALL will be faster than UNION.  In my experience, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much info about your table structure, but you can probably just do a plain old insert from a select, like below.  The example would take all records that don't already exist Table2 and Table3, and insert them into Table1.  You could do this to merge everything from all your 12 tables into a single table.

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
WHERE SomeUniqueKey
NOT IN (SELECT SomeUniqueKey FROM Table1)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table3
WHERE SomeUniqueKey
NOT IN (SELECT SomeUniqueKey FROM Table1)
--...
```

Comment: Jim if he's looking to move all records I don't the the `WHERE` and `NOT IN` clauses are necessary.

Comment: @Zane, as I mentioned in my post, this is inserting records from Table2 and Table3 into Table1, where the records don't already exist in Table1.  It seems pretty clear what the WHERE clause is for if you understand SQL.

Comment: I do understand SQL and I also unserstand the OP's question. He said he needs all of this information combined into one location therfore no where clause is not required as it would slow the query down considerably. He has 100's of millions of rcords in each of these tables you are really going to want to use a NOT IN statement? Where this 100 Million is NOT IN that 100 Million.

Comment: Would it be faster/more expedient to use an Insert Into function or to just use SQL Server's Import/export tool?  Does the Insert Into clause assume the same datatypes already in the table that is being imported into?

Answer (score 1):

Do what Jim says, but first:

1) Drop (or disable) all indices in the destination table.

2) Insert rows from each table, one table at a time.

3) Commit the transaction after each table is appended, otherwise much disk space will be taken up in case of a possible rollback.

4) Renable or recreate the indices after you are done.

If there is a possibility of duplicate keys, you may need to retain an index on the key field and have a NOT EXISTS clause to hold back the duplicate records from being added.